Is there a way to continue the loop of sending messages to MQTT broker after each ID flag called?
I have 2 programs:
"updatethread.h":
#ifndef
#define
#include <QThread>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <vector>
#include <QString>
#include "concurrent.h"

class updatethread:public QThread
{
    private:
        static updatethread *instance;
        std::string TOPIC_SET_NORMAL, TOPIC_SET_UPDATE;
        std::string TOPIC_GET_NORMAL, TOPIC_GET_UPDATE;
        Q_OBJECT;
    public slots:
        void Continue_receiver(void);
    public:
        explicit updatethread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
        void run();
        static updatethread* getInstance();
        bool isUpdate = false;
        bool isContinue = false;
        bool update_single = false;
        bool update_all = false;
        bool case_flag = false;
        bool DoneID;
        int Index_PCB;
        std::string get_topic_set_normal(void);
        std::string get_topic_set_update(void);
        std::string get_topic_get_normal(void);
        std::string get_topic_get_update(void);
        void set_topic_normal(std::string,std::string);
        void set_topic_update(std::string,std::string);
    private:
        QVector<int> Index_PCB_values;
};

#endif

"updatethread.cpp":
#include "updatethread.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <common.h>
#include <filehandle.h>
#include "mqtt.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <vector>

concurrent Concurrent_obj;

updatethread::updatethread(QObject *parent) : QThread (parent){}

updatethread* updatethread::getInstance()
{
    if(instance)
    {
        instance = new updatethread();
    }
    return instance;
}

void updatethread::run()
{
    uint32_t i;
    qDebug() << "Main thread is running";
    while(isUpdate && update_all)
    {
        DoneID = false;
        Index_PCB_values.append(Index_PCB);
        Index_PCB_values.pop_back();
        for(int i=0; i<Index_PCB_values.size(); i++)
        {
            switch(Index_PCB_values[i])
            {
                case 1:
                    while(case_flag)
                    {
                        /*Messages to MQTT broker*/
                        
                        /*Messages end*/
                        isContinue = false;
                        case_flag = false;
                        DoneID = true;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    while(case_flag)
                    {
                        /*Messages to MQTT broker*/
                        
                        /*Messages end*/
                        isContinue = false;
                        case_flag = false;
                        DoneID = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    isUpdate = false;
    update_all = false;
    if(updatethread::getInstance()->DoneID = true)
    {
        Concurrent_obj.stop_slot();
    }
}

void updatethread::Continue_receiver(void)
{
    qDebug() << "Continue signal";
    this->isContinue = true;
}

std::string updatethread::get_topic_set_normal(void)
{
    return this->TOPIC_SET_NORMAL;
}

std::string updatethread::get_topic_set_update(void)
{
    return this->TOPIC_SET_UPDATE;
}

std::string updatethread::get_topic_get_normal(void)
{
    return this->TOPIC_GET_NORMAL;
}

std::string updatethread::get_topic_get_update(void)
{
    return this->TOPIC_GET_UPDATE;
}

void updatethread::set_topic_normal(std::string str_set, std::string str_get)
{
    this->TOPIC_SET_NORMAL = str_set;
    this->TOPIC_GET_NORMAL = str_get;
}

void updatethread::set_topic_update(std::string str_set, std::string str_get)
{
    this->TOPIC_SET_UPDATE = str_set;
    this->TOPIC_GET_UPDATE = str_get;
}

Allow me to explicit how this program works: I attach multiple Index_PCB values to Index_PCB_values vector
, then for each Index_PCB_values[i] I put them in a switch case to process the transmission of messages
to MQTT broker, DoneID flag is called when the process is over. However, as of right now, for example a QVector(2,1)
the programs have only managed to send the messages to MQTT broker via the Index_PCB_values[i] = 2, how can i alter the
if(updatethread::getInstance()->DoneID = true){Concurrent_obj.stop_slot();} condition so that when the transmission finishes
on Index_PCB_values[i] = 2, it continues the transmission on Index_PCB_values[i] = 1 ?
